# Distorted blender UV face unwraping

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

here i try to unwrap this face and i get faces unwraped randomly.
tried to search for solution but all i found was for versions earlier than 2.77 and as you can see im using 2.77, where some options are in different places and some are not there!

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend using our friendly service known as http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You need to mark seams somewhere before the model can be unwrapped. Select edges and hit ctrl-E -> mark seam

Comment: What is your goal?

Do you have a texture already made?

Are you planning on painting a detailed one?

Does the texture need to look right from all angles?

UV unwrapping a face has similar problems as trying to put a map of a spherical planet onto a flat piece of paper.

Lots of different ways of doing it but some distortion is inevitable.

here are some different possibilities: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/6e/52/e7/6e52e71165b3cd4527c6b5f00ac103dd.jpg

here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-ZmDKuB6HI

Comment: the model came with textures so im trying to unwrap it so i can modify it or repaint it

Answer (score -1):

a little tip to use already found solutions. you can easily use as many versions of blender as you need. it doesn't need any installation. just download earlier version in another folder and run it from there. this way you can use solutions for previous versions, save your file and then continue in your favorite one later.
it's not so weird as it sounds, at least for blender. it can do some things better in the very version only.